# MySQL: Joins with inner WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, join

[EDIT]

I have now discovered the flaw in this approach. It works well when there is a crew member defined for every position, but completely skips the rows where some crew positions are not filled in.

This is undesirable, only from the perspective that every crew must have a crew leader and a driver, but every other position after that could be empty.

Any thoughts on how to do that? Reading up, it looks like I might have to simulate some sort of full outer join.

[ORIGINAL]

My database has a table for users (called ign_users):

```
-----------------------------------
¦ user_id ¦ RealName  ¦ surname   ¦
-----------------------------------
¦ 1       ¦ Alpha     ¦ Smith     ¦
-----------------------------------
¦ 2       ¦ Bravo     ¦ Jones     ¦
-----------------------------------
¦ 3       ¦ Charlie   ¦ Brown     ¦
-----------------------------------
¦ 4       ¦ Delta     ¦ White     ¦
-----------------------------------
```

I have created a new table to create crews (called as_crew):

```
------------------------------------------------
¦ name  ¦ crew_leader ¦ driver ¦ crew3 ¦ crew4 ¦
------------------------------------------------
¦ A     ¦ 1           ¦ 2      ¦ 3     ¦ 4     ¦
------------------------------------------------
¦ B     ¦ 2           ¦ 4      ¦ 1     ¦ 2     ¦
------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to be able to do is join the two so that I get the full name (ie. RealName and surname) for each person on the crew.

I can do this one person at a time. For example, the following will return the full name of the crew leader:

```
SELECT c.name, CONCAT(u.RealName, ' ', surname)
FROM as_crew c, ign_users u
WHERE c.crew_leader=u.user_id
```

However, I get errors when I try to join this together with another query, eg:

```
SELECT c.name, CONCAT(u.RealName, ' ', surname)
FROM as_crew c, ign_users u
WHERE c.crew_leader=u.user_id
JOIN
  (SELECT c.name, CONCAT(u.RealName, ' ', surname)
   FROM as_crew c, ign_users u
   WHERE c.DRIVER=u.user_id) AS t
ON c.name=t.name
```

I think this is due to the WHERE clauses, but I can't figure out how to get this result if I simply remvoe them from inside the SELECT statements and put them on the outside.

For crew3 and crew4 (and others - they go up to crew8), I just want to concatenate the crew together into one result.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the Error Message you get. Perhaps it complains that c.DRIVER is ambigious (c is assigned in the inner and in the outer Query).

Comment: Error message is - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN (SELECT c.name, CONCAT(u.RealName, ' ', surname) FROM as_crew c, ign_users ' at line 1. But I thought the inner one is referenced with the alias of t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would try to normalize the data to one row per crew.  From THAT, do your join... I've added extra columns in the final output to see how/where the records come from that you can ultimately strip out.

If you want only a specific Crew, Just add the same "WHERE" clause to each "SELECT/FROM" as its breaking down into individual rows... as I've commented with { } below

```
select
      PreQuery.Name,
      PreQuery.CrewPosition,
      PreQuery.PersonID,
      CONCAT(u.RealName, ' ', U.surname) as  PersonsName
   from
      ( select  c.Name, 
                "Crew Leader " as CrewPosition,
                c.Crew_Leader as PersonID
           from as_crew c
           { SPECIFIC WHERE CLAUSE }
        union 
        select  c.Name, 
                "Driver      " as CrewPosition,
                c.Driver as PersonID
           from as_crew c
           { SPECIFIC WHERE CLAUSE }
        union 
        select  c.Name, 
                "Crew3       " as CrewPosition,
                c.Crew3 as PersonID
           from as_crew c
           { SPECIFIC WHERE CLAUSE }
        union 
        select  c.Name, 
                "Crew4       " as CrewPosition,
                c.Crew4 as PersonID
           from as_crew c 
           { SPECIFIC WHERE CLAUSE }  ) PreQuery

      JOIN ign_users u
         on PreQuery.PersonID = u.User_ID
```

Here's a solution to get all people on a single row...
Revised per comment feedback.

```
select
      c.Name,
      CONCAT(CL.RealName, ' ', CL.surname) as  CrewLeader,
      CONCAT(dr.RealName, ' ', dr.surname) as  Driver,
      CONCAT( CONCAT(c3.RealName, ' ', c3.surname), ', '
              CONCAT(c4.RealName, ' ', c4.surname) as OtherCrew
   from
      as_crew c
         join ign_users CL
            on c.Crew_Leader = CL.User_ID
         join ign_users dr
            on c.Driver = dr.User_ID
         join ign_users c3
            on c.Crew3 = c4.User_ID
         join ign_users c4
            on c.Crew4 = c4.User_ID
```

Finally...  If a given crew does NOT have all members.. such as only a crew leader and driver, but no Crew3 or Crew4, just change those to LEFT JOIN instead of regular JOIN.

Comment: A question/followups. There is only one row per crew eg. crew A has one row, with multiple fields represent each crew member. Or have I got that wrong? But I will try this out.

Comment: @ASLSW, Correct... hence the union is grabbing the crew name and each person of their respective position WITHIN the crew.  So this is taking 1 row of 4 people and creating 4 rows each with one person in the crew.  THEN, it gets the people's respective names.

Comment: I understand now - the reason for this is about how I get the data in to the table. This is the closest I've got so far (thanks!). I pulled out the repeated crews and just concentrated on the crew leader and driver. The only problem I have is that it returns each crew position on a separate line. Because I want to display all crews, I would prefer to have each crew on one line, with the crew leader, driver and other crew members appearing horizontally on the line.

Comment: OK, that works perfectly - just needed to add a CONCAT at the start of each row for the names! For a bonus point, would I be able to group all of the additional crew members (ie. crew3 to crew 8) into a single column? So that the crew leader and driver can have more prominence.

Comment: @ASLSW, revised, just concatinated Crew 3 and 4... but you can concat as many as you need.. just need to keep nesting them I guess.

Comment: @ASLSW, did you get a chance to see the revised answer for all names in the crew on one row...

Comment: sorry long weekend. That works perfectly, except or spare commas where a field is empty. But this is so close it is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT c1.name, CONCAT(u.RealName, ' ', surname)
FROM as_crew c1, ign_users u
JOIN
  ( (SELECT c.name, CONCAT(u.RealName, ' ', surname)
   FROM as_crew c, ign_users u
   WHERE c.DRIVER=u.user_id) AS t
ON c1.name=t.name )
WHERE c1.crew_leader=u.user_id
```

Do you still get the errors?

Comment: Just tried that out, with the result "Unknown column 'c.name' in 'on clause'" which is weird - can't figure that out!

Comment: added some paranthesis and modified the table alias to c1 in the first select - i think it was ambiguous - try and see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately, still returns an error. "...near 'ON c1.name=t.name ) WHERE c1.crew_leader=u.user_id' ". But thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use the join keyword in the context of union. IE you want to 'join' results to each other.

```
SELECT c.name, CONCAT( u.RealName, ' ', surname )
FROM as_crew c, ign_users u
WHERE c.crew_leader = u.user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT c.name, CONCAT( u.RealName, ' ', surname )
FROM as_crew c, ign_users u
WHERE c.DRIVER = u.user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT c.name, CONCAT( u.RealName, ' ', surname )
FROM as_crew c, ign_users u
WHERE c.crew3 = u.user_id
```

and so on.

Edit : I'd make another table for driver numbers pointing at crew numbers, so you can just have a couple of where statements and you don't have to update all your table structures if your crew size changes, for example.

Edit2 :
Try this out.

```
SELECT c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT( ' ',u.RealName, ' ', u.surname )) 
FROM as_crew c, ign_users u
WHERE c.driver = u.user_id OR c.crew_leader = u.user_id  
OR c.crew3 = u.user_id 
OR c.crew4 = u.user_id 
OR c.crew5 = u.user_id 
OR c.crew6 = u.user_id 
OR c.crew7 = u.user_id 
OR c.crew8 = u.user_id
GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: This works, but has the similar problem to DRapp's solution in that everything is put out on a separate row (instead of one row for the entire crew). But I think I can get around that by GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: That puts everything on a single line, although it needed a GROUP BY clause on the end.

Comment: oops, mustve missed it on the copy paste. Sorry about that, tis right now.